# Open modal window - PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt

Im using Python 3.8 and hv installed QTDesigner. I defined a main window with menus that link to modal windows. I haven't succeed that yet. The aplication opens the main window succesfully, but whe I click on the menu, it closes the program. Here is the generated code :
Main file Principal.py

```
  from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton, QDialog, QVBoxLayout, QLabel
import JanelaModal1, JanelaEnvRetDocs

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menuCONSULTAS = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuCONSULTAS.setObjectName("menuCONSULTAS")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.actionEnvRetDocs = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionEnvRetDocs.setObjectName("actionEnvRetDocs")
        #self.actionEnvRetDocs.triggered.connect(self.abrir_janela_modal)
        self.actionEnvRetDocs.triggered.connect(self.abrirJanelaEnvRetDocs)

        self.actionDocsUnid = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionDocsUnid.setObjectName("actionDocsUnid")
        self.actionDigitDocs = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionDigitDocs.setObjectName("actionDigitDocs")
        self.actionDigitUnid = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionDigitUnid.setObjectName("actionDigitUnid")
        self.menuCONSULTAS.addAction(self.actionEnvRetDocs)
        self.menuCONSULTAS.addAction(self.actionDocsUnid)
        self.menuCONSULTAS.addAction(self.actionDigitDocs)
        self.menuCONSULTAS.addAction(self.actionDigitUnid)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuCONSULTAS.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.menuCONSULTAS.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "CONSULTAS"))
        self.actionEnvRetDocs.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Envio/Retorno Docs"))
        self.actionDocsUnid.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Docs/Unidade"))
        self.actionDigitDocs.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Digitação Docs"))
        self.actionDigitUnid.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Digitação/Unidade"))

    def abrir_janela_modal(self):
        janela_modal = JanelaModal1.JanelaModal1()
        janela_modal.exec_()  # Exibe a janela modal

    def abrirJanelaEnvRetDocs(self):
        print("1")
        janela_modal1 = JanelaEnvRetDocs.Ui_jnlEnvRetDocs()
        janela_modal1.exec_()  # Exibe a janela modal


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

File JanelaEnvRetDocs.py :

```
  from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

  class Ui_jnlEnvRetDocs(object):
    def setupUi(self, jnlEnvRetDocs):
        jnlEnvRetDocs.setObjectName("jnlEnvRetDocs")
        jnlEnvRetDocs.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.WindowModal)
        jnlEnvRetDocs.resize(489, 582)
        jnlEnvRetDocs.setModal(True)
        self.lblTitulo = QtWidgets.QLabel(jnlEnvRetDocs)
        self.lblTitulo.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 10, 181, 31))
        self.lblTitulo.setObjectName("lblTitulo")
        self.lblTipo = QtWidgets.QLabel(jnlEnvRetDocs)
        self.lblTipo.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 60, 51, 31))
        self.lblTipo.setObjectName("lblTipo")
        self.cmbTpDoc = QtWidgets.QComboBox(jnlEnvRetDocs)
        self.cmbTpDoc.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 70, 69, 22))
        self.cmbTpDoc.setObjectName("cmbTpDoc")
        self.cmbTpDoc.addItem("")
        self.cmbTpDoc.addItem("")
        self.lblDtInicial = QtWidgets.QLabel(jnlEnvRetDocs)
        self.lblDtInicial.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 120, 81, 21))
        self.lblDtInicial.setObjectName("lblDtInicial")
        self.calDtInicial = QtWidgets.QCalendarWidget(jnlEnvRetDocs)
        self.calDtInicial.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 120, 256, 101))
        self.calDtInicial.setObjectName("calDtInicial")
        self.lblDtFinal = QtWidgets.QLabel(jnlEnvRetDocs)
        self.lblDtFinal.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 260, 71, 21))
        self.lblDtFinal.setObjectName("lblDtFinal")
        self.calendarWidget = QtWidgets.QCalendarWidget(jnlEnvRetDocs)
        self.calendarWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 260, 256, 183))
        self.calendarWidget.setObjectName("calendarWidget")
        self.btnEnviar = QtWidgets.QPushButton(jnlEnvRetDocs)
        self.btnEnviar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 490, 75, 23))
        self.btnEnviar.setObjectName("btnEnviar")

        self.retranslateUi(jnlEnvRetDocs)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(jnlEnvRetDocs)

        def retranslateUi(self, jnlEnvRetDocs):
          _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
           jnlEnvRetDocs.setWindowTitle(_translate("jnlEnvRetDocs", "Consulta do Envio e Retorno de  Documentos"))
        self.lblTitulo.setText(_translate("jnlEnvRetDocs", "ENVIO/RETORNO DE DOCUMENTOS"))
        self.lblTipo.setText(_translate("jnlEnvRetDocs", "Tipo :"))
        self.cmbTpDoc.setItemText(0, _translate("jnlEnvRetDocs", "DNs"))
        self.cmbTpDoc.setItemText(1, _translate("jnlEnvRetDocs", "DOs"))
        self.lblDtInicial.setText(_translate("jnlEnvRetDocs", "Data Inicial :"))
        self.lblDtFinal.setText(_translate("jnlEnvRetDocs", "Data Final :"))
        self.btnEnviar.setText(_translate("jnlEnvRetDocs", "CONSULTAR"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    jnlEnvRetDocs = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_jnlEnvRetDocs()
    ui.setupUi(jnlEnvRetDocs)
    jnlEnvRetDocs.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Those `Ui_` classes are just helper classes used to create the UI within a QWidget, they are not *the* widget (or window) and won't do anything on their own. You need to create a widget (QDialog, in the above cases) instance and call `setupUi()` on that, otherwise create a subclass that *also* inherits from the UI. In any case, you should **never** edit a pyuic file (there is a clear warning on top of them, but you ignored and removed it), but properly follow the official guidelines about [using Designer](//www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html).

Comment: def abrirJanelaEnvRetDocs4(self):
        widget = QDialog(self)
        ui = Ui_jnlEnvRetDocs()
        ui.setupUi(widget)
        ui.exec_()

Comment: If fact, what Im looking for is a function that attach a menu item to open a new window. Does Qt Designer do that automatically ?